# Change or remove null value when printing search method

Tags: java

I am making a method in which I compare 2 values and if they are equal I store the different results in an array, what happens is that the null values are printed. I would like to know how I can replace those null values with blanks or directly delete them.

```
    public String Search(String type) {
        String[] animalTypes;
        animalTypes = new String[50];
        for (int i = 0; i < animals.length; i++) {
            if (animals[i] != null) {
                while (animals[i].getClassification().equalsIgnoreCase(type)) {
                    animalTypes[i] = animals[i].getName();
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

            String printAnimalTypes = Arrays.toString(animalTypes);
            return printAnimalTypes;
    }
```

The idea would be that at the moment of storing the array it would ask if it was null and if so it would not store it so that at the moment of printing it would not print it.

Comment: You'd be much better off describing your goal in plain language without technical terms. It's difficult to know what you want, and at the moment, your inner loop makes little sense at all, running either not at all or once per outer

Answer (score 1):

There are many types of ways you can store multiple values, they are called [Collections](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html).
Arrays are great at storing values, but bad at taking one out, because they are numbered, and you can't just take one out. (see above)

So instead just use a list, and convert it into an array if you must.

```
public String Search(String type) {
    List<String> animalList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < animals.length; i++) {
        if (animals[i] != null) {
            while (animals[i].getClassification().equalsIgnoreCase(type)) {
                animalList.add(animals[i].getName());
                break;
            }
        }

        String[] animalTypes = animalList.toArray(new String[0]);
        String printAnimalTypes = Arrays.toString(animalTypes);
        return printAnimalTypes;
```

Answer (score 0):

You code initializes the array and then selectively puts the elements in it (leaving the interm values as null). For example - if the animals at index `0` and `3` match the type, only the array elements `0` and `3` will be initialized with the name (leaving the values at `1` and `2` as `null`).

One way you can handle this is to put a separate index/counter variable that you increment only if there is a match.

Another way is to replace your `while` condition with an `if` condition and add a 'blank' in the else part

Comment: the counter where would it go? because it could not be placed after the while because it would not detect the animalTypes variable.

Comment: You could put the counter outside the loops so that it is available inside the block where you need it. Only increase it once you have found a match and inserted an element in the `animalTypes` array. 

Having said that, you will still be better off changing the `animalTypes` to a List as suggested in the answer by @Windir